# batch processing: userPrincipalName already exists when trying to add multiple users async in AAD

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to add multiple users async with AAD graph Like this:

```
IUser user1 = ...;
IUser user2 = ...;
IUser user3 = ...;
List<Task> addTasks = new List<Task>();
addTasks.Add(activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(user1));
addTasks.Add(activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(user2));
addTasks.Add(activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(user3));
await Task.WhenAll(addTasks);
```

I get this error message :

> {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Another object with the same value for property userPrincipalName already exists."},"values":[{"item":"PropertyName","value":"userPrincipalName"},{"item":"PropertyErrorCode","value":"ObjectConflict"}]}}

If I use this code :

```
IUser user1 = ...;
IUser user2 = ...;
IUser user3 = ...;
List<Task> addTasks = new List<Task>();
await activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(user1);
await activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(user2);
await activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(user3);
```

This is working well.

Maybe we can't add multiple users in AAD at the same time ?

**EDIT**
Here is the users part:

```
IUser newStudentUser = new User
{
    DisplayName = $"Etudiant de l'école {school}",
    UserPrincipalName = $"etudiant-{school}@........fr",
    AccountEnabled = true,
    MailNickname = $"Etudiant {school}",
    UsageLocation = "US",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        Password = "......."
    }
};
IUser newTeacherUser = new User
{
    DisplayName = $"Professeur de l'école {school}",
    UserPrincipalName = $"professeur-{school}@........fr",
    AccountEnabled = true,
    MailNickname = $"Professeur {school}",
    UsageLocation = "US",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        Password = "......."
    }
};
IUser newDirectorUser = new User
{
    DisplayName = $"Directeur de l'école {school}",
    UserPrincipalName = $"directeur-{school}@........fr",
    AccountEnabled = true,
    MailNickname = $"Directeur {school}",
    UsageLocation = "US",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        Password = "......."
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe your `...`s contain code where some objects have ended up shared between all 3 `user` variables and so setting a value on one is setting the same value for all 3 "independent" variables. I'd have thought that far more likely. Can't confirm since you've elided that code.

Comment: I have added the users creation part. But i don't think it can be that because its working with the `await ...; await ...; await ...;` method

Comment: Can you rename your question so that it could be related to batch processing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you want to batch the creation of multiple users.

At present, the GraphClient does support batch processing but there are some limitation ([Batch processing | Graph API concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing)):

- A single batch can contain a maximum of five queries and/or change sets combined.
- A change set can contain a maximum of one source object modification and up to 20 add-link and delete-link operations combined. All operations in the change set must be on a single source entity.

So in your case **you can't batch the creation of more than 5 users**.

While adding an entity to Graph API client, you can choose to defer the execution of the query using the `deferredSave` parameter.

```
await activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(user, deferredSave: true);
```

The Graph API client has a `DataServiceContextWrapper` that tracks changes. It provides a `SaveChanges(Async)` method.

```
await activeDirectoryClient.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Calling this method you can specify the [SaveChangesOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.savechangesoptions(v=vs.113).aspx):

- Batch: All pending changes are saved in a single batch request.
- **BatchWithIndependentOperations**: the one you want to use because the creation of the user should be in a single query.
- ContinueOnError: Pending changes are saved by using multiple requests to the server, and the operation continues after an error occurs.
- None: Pending changes are saved by using multiple requests to the server, but the operation stops on the first failure (default).
- PatchOnUpdate:
- ReplaceOnUpdate: Pending updates are made by replacing all values of the entity in the data source with values from the updated entity.

Now you have enough information to write the code to batch the creation of the users:

```
// Only 5 users per batch !!!!
var user1 = ...;
var user2 = ...;
var user3 = ...;
await activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(newStudentUser, deferredSave: true);
await activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(newTeacherUser, deferredSave: true);
await activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(newDirectorUser, deferredSave: true);

// In debug mode, you should use the SaveChangesAsync method with the default options
// Becasue the BatchWithIndependentOperations will not throw any exception even if there is a problem while creating the user.
//await activeDirectoryClient.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
await activeDirectoryClient.Context
    .SaveChangesAsync(SaveChangesOptions.BatchWithIndependentOperations);
```

Comment: I'm using the same code as yours to loop on a list of users to create. but I get an exception, **"The context is already tracking the entity"** I'm using your same code but with a list of users and a loop, it's really frustrating as I'm stuck with this error for a couple of days

Comment: @AhmedHamdy, where does your list come from ? How do you create your user list ? Feel  free to ask a new question and post you code

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, please find my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429710/create-multiple-users-azure-active-directory

Comment: Ok I ll have a look and tell you if I find something

Comment: thank you so much for your effort, I found the bug in my code

Comment: @AhmedHamdy, no worries, is it something that can help someone else ?

Comment: actually it was a beginner mistake as I didn't "new" each user and used the same object instead of creating a new one